# Let's nuke a tag down to its [origins]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

We have five questions tagged [origins](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/origins).

Three are about origins of something (history).
One is about the screen positioning (with origin at 0,0), and one is about a game client.

I propose to be unoriginal in our nuking.

Comment: My initial reaction was to completely agree.  Now I'm not so sure because of the history meaning.  We don't want people to misuse the [history] tag for this meaning.  Are origin history questions on topic?  With only three previous uses for this purpose, people obviously aren't picking tags with a thesaurus.  Might it be useful to create a [history-origin] tag?  That, at least, would pop up when the poster selects a tag, which might help to keep the [history] tag usage true to its definition.  And if origin history questions are off-topic, the wiki excerpt could include usage guidance.

Comment: I am not sure history style origin would be on-topic, though I personally like some question which would fit that. Then we would have to fill the tag descrion properly though, or retag to [history-origins].  Giving it a good description and removing it from the gameclient and coordinates question seems easy to do.

Comment: I would agree that `origin` is not a helpful tag and should be nuked.  Its being used to ask opinionated and questions [1](http://superuser.com/questions/174945/what-are-the-origins-of-the-control-and-alt-keys)[2](http://superuser.com/questions/185980/what-is-the-origin-of-the-hard-drive-light), one other [question](http://superuser.com/questions/968724/origin-from-ea-prevents-windows-10-from-sleep-and-does-not-require-password) does not even used it correctly. There are very few questions where the community can answer why something was done, which is what both of those questions, were asking

Comment: It's five questions, and there aren't origin experts, no matter the sense of the word. I'd say this is an easy call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a meta tag. Its trivial to get rid of. I say we get rid of the tag. (And... when I check its gone ;p)